# CSS style for parent table first <td> in a nested table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add some css style to the first **td** element of my parent table only but if i use `td:first-child {width: 18%;}` it is applying to the child table first **td** also. So, is there any css selector to select the parent table only ?

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}

td:first-child {
  width: 18%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <label>Parent first td</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Child first td</td>
          <td>Child second td</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to look at CSS [combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp), it could help you. And take a look on [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the parent table a class name and use immediate child selector `>` as followings:

```css
table,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}


.parent-table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
/*                    ^^   ^^     */
/* Means 'first "td" child of first order "tr" children of ".parent-table" */
  width: 18%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="parent-table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Parent first td</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Child first td</td>
          <td>Child second td</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Harun but it seems it's not working, here is a fiddle i have created based on your answer - https://jsfiddle.net/569nmcwh/

Comment: Ah you're right. Modern browsers  automatically add `tbody` tag if there's not. So you need to add `.parent-table > tbody > ...` in order it to work. Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just add any specific class(like `<tr class="t1">` to your parent table's tr and then use smth like:

```
.t1>td:first-child { 
  background-color: lime;
}
```

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Won't this style also be applied to first `td` of inner table?

Comment: No, if it's not using the same class, as style will be applied to only first appearance of td after the table with class .t1

Comment: If you don't use immediate child selector, it will also be applied to the inner one. You can check [this](https://codepen.io/hedegitsinue/pen/ZEWMdaL) out.

Comment: @Undry It's not working, please check this out https://jsfiddle.net/ja62ygkt/